# In Typescript, how to check if an object has been disposed?

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I'm using [this call](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserclose) to `browser.close()` in order to close a Puppeteer-controlled browser. Looking at the documentation for this method call, it states:

> Closes Chromium and all of its pages (if any were opened). The Browser object itself is considered to be disposed and cannot be used anymore.

My question is: How can I check if the `browser` object has been successfully disposed? Using `browser.isConnected()` doesn't work because accessing `browser` throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `browser.isConnected`. If for you it's throwing an exception, it's for another reason. Probably it's not on the scope where you are trying to access it.

Regards.

Comment: because he is calling a property like a method which does not exist